# Word is not spell checking?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-word-2016

I am making notes for uni on Word and recently Word has stopped automatially spell checking. After going into the Reveiw tab > Language > Set Proofing Language, I turned off "Do not check spelling or grammar" which had randomly turned on, however Word is now not picking up any mistakes that I made before I changed this back. This setting also changes back from time to time, so how can I stop this from changing back from unchecked to checked.

Furthermore, how can I make Word recognise the mistakes I made before so that I can correct them? I have found at least 2 that I made before I realised that this setting had checked itself, howver after I click on "Recheck Document" it still doesn't identify the mistakes that I made before I changed the setting back to what it should be.

Comment: Go to File > Options > Proofing > Scroll to the bottom area called Exceptions for, check if the Hide spelling errors in this document only is enabled.
If not, go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing Tools\1.0` , rename this folder 1.0, restart Word to check this issue. (Please [back up and restore the registry in Windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/322756) before modify registry.)

Comment: @Emily I have posted your comment as an answer. Please edit it if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This setting also changes back from time to time, so how can I stop
> this from changing back from unchecked to checked.

**(1)** Reset the Word Normal Template to default and restart Word. Instructions and support article follow here.

**(2)** For the damaged document, copy into a new Document without formatting.

**(3)** Now follow below to reset Normal.dotm

https://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/word/fix-word-2016-normal-template/

> Quit Word. Press Win+E to summon a File Explorer window. Click the
> Address box to select whatever name appears there. Press the Delete
> key to clear the Address box. Type
> %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates.
>
> As you start typing AppData, you see hints appear below your typing.
> These hints help to direct you and confirm that you’re on the right
> track. Eventually, you see the Templates folder.
>
> Right-click on the Normal.dotm file. The file might show only the
> first part of the name, Normal. Choose the Rename command from the
> shortcut menu. Edit the name to Normal-old.dotm or Normal-old. If you
> can see the dotm part of the name, don’t change it. Press Enter to
> lock in the new name. Keep the File Explorer window open. Restart
> Word.
>
> You don’t need to do anything in Word, though you may notice that any
> problems you have related to the old Normal template are gone. Quit
> Word.
>
> In the File Explorer window, you see the rebuilt Normal.dotm file.

**(4)** When done do a Full Repair of Office (use Control Panel to get to Office and Change,  Repair,   Full)

Answer (score 1):

In the comments, Emily has mentioned an important option:

> Go to `File` > `Options` > `Proofing` > Scroll to the bottom area called `Exceptions` for, check if the `Hide spelling errors in this document only` is enabled. If not, go to `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Shared Tools\Proofing Tools\1.0`, rename this folder 1.0, restart Word to check this issue. (Please back up and restore the registry in Windows before modify registry.)

[image: MS Word - Proofing - Hide spelling errors in this document only]

Answer (score 0):

This setting is also tied to character-level formatting.
Please see [Spelling Checker Does Not Work - Solutions](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-msoversion_other/proofing-language-keeps-changing-solutions-how-can/c6483d0c-6fe3-41bf-8464-25535d3ec15b?tm=1579788821357). This is an Article on the Microsoft Answers site I did last year. It addresses this problem as well as the problem of the wrong proofing language being applied.

Here are some keys ideas:

- Pasted text can carry this setting with it. It can feel like a virus!
- The setting can be in styles.

The page has macros you can use with instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Mac? I had this issue when I set up my new M1.

For some reason, my dictionary preference on word was set to using the "Custom Dictionary".

1. Go to "Word Preferences"
2. Select "Spelling & Grammar"
3. I had "Suggest from main dictionary only" checked.
4. I unchecked this and autocorrect started working again.

I was able to see the red underline and the options for the correct spellings when I clicked on the word.